# Ruby on Windows using Ruby irb, and how to set up RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started playing around with Ruby on Windows. I downloaded Ruby and started it with the command line with Ruby.

I typed in `irb` to the command prompt and it changed to the irb command prompt.

Then I started trying out commands like 1 => 1; and other things, but I got no output. I just go the next prompt. What ta heck am I doing with that? :)

What should I do to make sure I have RoR set up and start creating applications?

Thanks and sorry for the generally confused question.

Comment: are you certain that what you're typing into irb isn't expecting a closing quote?  What you've described sounds like you've typed an unterminated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `irb` you can tell if your current line is unterminated doesn't start with `>`.

```
irb(main):001:0> "I'm gonna wait
irb(main):002:0" to finish this string"    # The string isn't terminated
=> "I'm gonna wait\nto finish this string"
irb(main):003:0>
```

But more interestingly in `irb` it would seem that a semi-colon(`;`) it won't terminate the line. Since semi-colons(`;`) in`Ruby` aren't necessary and are just [meant to be statement separators](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#semicolon). `irb` won't actually run your statements until you end one **without** a semi-colon. *Also `1 => 1` isn't a valid `Ruby` statement.*

```
irb(main):001:0> string = ""
  => ""
irb(main):002:0> string << "I'm gonna run this line\n";
irb(main):003:0* string << "Plus this line\n"
  => "I'm gonna run this line\nPlus this line\n"
irb(main):004:0> string << "Semi-colons are not cool in Ruby"
  => "I'm gonna run this line\nPlus this line\nSemi-colons are not cool in Ruby"
irb(main):005:0>
```

So your problem should be solved by **NEVER** using semi-colons in `Ruby`

Also all these examples were run on Windows 7 using Powershell

```
PS C:\Users\Justin> ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]
```

As Aaron mentioned the best way to get started is probably [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/). I haven't used it personally, but it looks like it does pretty much everything for you.

*I use [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) and set up my Rails environment myself. RailsInstaller does all that for you.*

Answer (score 2):

Although I prefer using Ruby on Rails on a Mac, I have a soft place in my heart for Windows, so I set RoR up on my Windows machine a while back. But be forewarned, you may be setting yourself up for some heartache and pain. In addition to errors and badness, Ruby runs much slower on Windows. I would highly recommend setting up a dual boot or virtual machine with Linux and then putting Rails on your Linux OS instead of trying to set it up on Windows. You can use [Windows Virtual PC](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/366-how-to-run-linux-under-windows-7s-windows-virtual-pc/) or something similar if you want to go the virtual machine route.

But, if you still want to stick with Windows, I think one of the easiest ways to get everything installed is to use Wayne Seguin's [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/). Along these lines, I used [Agile Web Development With Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) to help me learn the process of getting Rails set up and to build my first app. Great book.

Hope this helps.